# How can I tell my app was started as a result of background refresh?

Tags: ios, events, background, refresh, restart

My iOS app is using background refresh (via the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: API), and I noticed that sometimes iOS will kill the app in the background and restart it again later.

In cases like this, it seems like application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is being called but applicationDidBecomeActive: is not being called because the app stays in the background.

The challenge I have is that I would like to know whether my app was restarted in the background as a result of background refresh in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function, since I do some early processing there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's being launched by remote notification, look for the launch key passed to `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

> Keys used to access values in the launch options dictionary passed to the application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods of the app delegate

In particular:

> `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`
>   The presence of this key indicates that a remote notification is available for the app to process. The value of this key is an NSDictionary containing the payload of the remote notification. See the description of application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: for further information about handling remote notifications.

If it's background fetch via an `NSURLSession`, Session 204 of WWDC 2013 has more info, but you implelent `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:`

[image]